# Standalone properties file for Java Jar file? How to set up the configuration for different servers?

Tags: java, php, properties, development-environment, executable-jar

So I have a runnable Java jar that contains Java library code that will be called by PHP, currently I am calling the application code in PHP like below:

$userIdinput = "abcd"; // parameter

exec("java -jar MyApplication.jar ".$userIdinput,$output);

print_r($output);

This jar file needs to run on different environments QA, Production and my local windows machine. The QA and production will be on a linux machine. Each of these environment will have their own different properties variables.

I am wondering what is the most efficient way of doing this that when I place the MyApplication.jar file at a server location, it will read the properties variables from a file that I placed somewhere on the server?

I have tried classpath but couldn't get it to work. Thanks very much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set different configuration is by using a configuration file. As you run it in your example, I assume the jar file is in your current directory. So, it is easy to have there also the configuration file and just read it form the current directory which is also the working directory for the java application.

In your code you can do something like: `File f = new File("configuration")` and that will try to find a file in your current working directory, with the name configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is probably not very secure if `$userIdinput` does indeed come from some user input. They could potentially escape out of your command execute something arbitrary on your server.

At minimum, if you *must* use exec at all, validate the input as much as possible first (if it should be an integer, cast it or error out if it's not) - and also use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

It's slightly unclear what you're asking - but if you're trying to load propery variables from a file on the server in PHP, then there's a number of ways to accomplish this. You could create an ini file with a relative path, for example:

```
$properties = parse_ini_file("../local_properties.ini");
 exec("java -jar MyApplication.jar ".escapeshellarg ( $properties['userIdinput']),$output);
```

Then the ini file would simply need to define the local properties:

```
; Your local property:
userIdinput = ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is for your Java program to look for a properties file in the current directory, e.g. `MyApplication.properties`. As long as the caller sets the current directory to the directory containing the Jar file (which your `exec` example would indicate since the .jar is unqualified), your Java program can find it.

On Linux, `MyApplication.properties` could then be a symbolic link to the real file, likely stored in `/etc`.

This code would not be dependent on operating system, but allow each installation to specify its own local configuration values.